# SQL Logic not working

Tags: sql, oracle

Table Input

```
Origin   Product     Supplier  
Quebec   Copper                   
Quebec   Diamond                
Canada   Copper                   
Canada   Diamond
```

Table Output

```
Origin   Product     Supplier  
Quebec   Copper                   
Quebec   Diamond                
Canada   Copper      Raglan             
Canada   Diamond     Eustis
```

Desired Output

```
Origin   Product     Supplier  
Canada   Copper      Raglan             
Canada   Diamond     Eustis           
Canada   Copper      Raglan             
Canada   Diamond     Eustis
```

Logic for "Origin"

If Quebec then Canada

Logic for "Supplier"

- If "Origin" in Canada and "Product" in Copper then 'Raglan'
- If "Origin" in Canada and "Product" in Diamond then 'Eustis'

Question

Hi All, what I was trying to do is have automatically add in the "Supplier"

- If "Origin" in Canada and "Product" in Copper "Supplier" should be 'Raglan'
- If "Origin" in Canada and "Product" in Diamond "Supplier" should be 'Eustis'

The only thing that works is changing "Origin" from 'Quebec' to 'Canada' but the "Supplier" query is not working and remains blank. but when 'Canada' is in the "Origin" it fills up the " Supplier" correctly.

I used the logic above and I was able to transform "Origin" from Quebec to Canada but the "Supplier" remains blank for lines 1-2, yet for line 3-4 the transformation is working. Im kind of new to this and I also do not know what this is overall process is, is this called SQL? Can someone help me have the supplier column to be in the output with the correct logic?

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the query you tried. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). [Edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: How do you specify the logic? through SQL query then I think your result is expected because the "logics" are processed in 1 query. 
If you want the result as what you expect, you should query the "Logic for "Origin" first, then query "Logic for "Supplier""  after that, in total 2 queries

Comment: For this case Quebec   Copper  it should be blank. It is expected correct ?

Comment: Im using Oracle PL-SQL...

Comment: Rather than writing *descriptions* of what your code does, why not post *the actual code* (or a trimmed down version that still matches the question)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do desired query with proper CASE

```
SELECT A.ORIGIN
     , A.PRODUCT
     , CASE WHEN A.ORIGIN = 'Canada' AND PRODUCT='Copper' THEN 'Raglan'
            WHEN A.ORIGIN = 'Canada' AND PRODUCT='Diamond' THEN 'Eustis'
            ELSE NULL END AS SUPPLIER
FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN ORIGIN='Quebec' THEN 'Canada' ELSE ORIGIN END  AS ORIGIN
            , PRODUCT
      FROM T_P) A
```

But I think it should be better create a sort of "decod" tables (you can simply add more "origin" values and "product" values than using a specific CASE instruction).

In the query, join your main table with "decod" tables to generate new value and `COALESCE` to extract new value (you need `COALESCE` to leave original value when you dont't find it in decod table).

You should use codes and not description.

Eg.

```
LEFT JOIN DECOD_O B ON A.ORIGIN = B.ORIGIN
```

and

```
COALESCE(B.FINAL, A.ORIGIN) ORIGIN_NEW
```

Sample data

```
CREATE TABLE T_P (ORIGIN VARCHAR2(10), PRODUCT VARCHAR2(10))
INSERT INTO T_P VALUES ('Quebec','Copper');
INSERT INTO T_P VALUES ('Quebec','Diamond');
INSERT INTO T_P VALUES ('Canada','Copper');
INSERT INTO T_P VALUES ('Canada','Diamond');


CREATE TABLE DECOD_O (ORIGIN VARCHAR2(10), FINAL VARCHAR2(10))
INSERT INTO DECOD_O VALUES ('Quebec', 'Canada')

CREATE TABLE DECOD_S (ORIGIN VARCHAR2(10), PRODUCT VARCHAR2(10), FINAL VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO DECOD_S VALUES ('Canada', 'Copper', 'Raglan')
INSERT INTO DECOD_S VALUES ('Canada', 'Diamond', 'Eustlis')
```

Query

```
SELECT  COALESCE(B.FINAL, A.ORIGIN) AS ORIGIN_NEW
      , A.PRODUCT
      , C.FINAL AS SUPPLIER
FROM T_P A
LEFT JOIN DECOD_O B ON A.ORIGIN = B.ORIGIN
LEFT JOIN DECOD_S C ON COALESCE(B.FINAL, A.ORIGIN) = C.ORIGIN 
                      AND A.PRODUCT = C.PRODUCT
```

Output:

```
+------------+---------+----------+
| ORIGIN_NEW | PRODUCT | SUPPLIER |
+------------+---------+----------+
| Canada     | Copper  | Raglan   |
| Canada     | Diamond | Eustlis  |
| Canada     | Copper  | Raglan   |
| Canada     | Diamond | Eustlis  |
+------------+---------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to do that by using simple `case` expression

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Origin = 'Quebec' THEN 'Canada' ELSE Origin END Origin,
       Product,
       CASE
           WHEN(Origin IN('Canada', 'Quebec') AND Product = 'Copper')
           THEN 'Raglan'
           WHEN(Origin IN('Canada', 'Quebec') AND Product = 'Diamond')
           THEN 'Eustis'
       END [Supplier]
FROM Table;
```

Result :

```
Origin   Product     Supplier  
Canada   Copper      Raglan             
Canada   Diamond     Eustis           
Canada   Copper      Raglan             
Canada   Diamond     Eustis
```